# CSS Flex Not Working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to `justify` a few images in a `div`.

I added `justify-content: center;`, but the images align left. Why?

```css
.item {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" />
  </div>
  <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" />
  </div>
  <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" />
  </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: How to you want to align elements?

Comment: Actually, either space-betwenn or space-around, but before trying those, I need to get this working.

Comment: But I am not sure what you are asking. With css, no?

Comment: You've applied class properly. But the question is how do you want this div to be styled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `justify-content` property *only* aligns the content/s of a given container if the container is a **flex**ible one.

Add this to your CSS:

```
display: flex;
```

The full CSS code in the head section should be:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .flex-item {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center; 
    }
</style>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_justify-content&preval=center

Fidde example: https://jsfiddle.net/L4tmgs18/1/

Comment: Oh, text/css is optional. display: flex line is needed because justify-content property works only with flexible elements.

Comment: well, i thought that you'd like to have them all centered in one line. How do you want them to look like then?

Comment: You need to add margins, width and height to img: https://jsfiddle.net/L4tmgs18/1/

Comment: Both solutions seems to work. It depends on what you want to achieve. In my case you can controll size of the img elements and the space between them. In yours it is done automatically so the images fill the row.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly and you're trying to center the contents of the .flex-item div (i.e. the icons), replace `justify-content: center;` with `text-align: center;`.

Your problem isn't with how you have applied the css, that is correct, but depending on what you are trying to achieve, your problem is with the actual css used.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for, check it out: http://codepen.io/lintonballdev/pen/GpOOBP?editors=100

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say space between. If you are referring to the space between the icons, adjust the amount of padding in the style up the top, there is currently 15px between each icon.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you have all the necessary code provided to you by "Hubert Siwkin", but it sits a tad off the left side of your page. Simple fix. You need to edit your "body" CSS style and add a "margin" value.

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
}
```

This will fix the problem you are facing.

If you would like to know more about the "body" CSS style, use the following link.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp

UPDATE: I have provided an update to the jsFiddle provided by "Hubert Siwkin". Most of the code that you have is not necessary, so I have slim-lined it for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/hddbkcvv/

Comment: Ok, I can mark your answer as correct (or maybe credit goes to Huber?), but would you know a place to put the css, for it to apply to all pages, or do I need to add it to each page?

Comment: But you didn't slim line it. It seems to work with a single div at start and end!

Comment: So it worked? You would have to place the CSS in all pages, otherwise try loading an external universal CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Got it. Who does the correct answer go to? Am I able to mark 2?

Comment: Check the chatroom for more info.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can mark both as correct, but I believe Hubert gave more of the answer you were looking for?

Comment: In fact, I cannot, so I marked his as correct, and upvoted yours.

Comment: Haha That's why I started helping others :)

Comment: How did the HTML linking go for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92791/discussion-between-dani-springer-and-jesse).